# EF cannot insert entity because key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-7.0

I'm trying to write some tests around my Entity Framework code, an as part of the isolation of logic, I'm inserting a model into the database like this:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated(
                $@"INSERT INTO MyModel(Id, Name, PostTown) 
                   VALUES({Id}, {myModel.Name}, {myModel.PostTown});");
```

I have several tests based around reading this entity using `_contest.Set<MyModel>().Find()` which all work as expected.

I'm now trying to write a test to ensure my update methods work, the test looks something like this:

```
MyModel myModel = new Model("AName", "ATown");

_context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated(
                $@"INSERT INTO MyModel(Id, Name, PostTown) 
                   VALUES({myModel.Id}, {myModel..Name}, {intermediary.PostTown});");

...

_context.Set<MyModel>.Update(myModel);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

However the update fails with an error:

> The instance of entity type 'MyModel' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Do I need to do something after my SQL insert to get EF to recognise the entity?

Comment: Is this `_context` instance used in multiple tests? If so: use a context per test.

Comment: No it's one per test, the issue is that I use the context at the start of the test to do an ```ExecuteSqlInterpolated``` then I later use it to do a ```Update```.  I think the issue is that EF maybe doesn't know that I've inserted the instance, and is assuming that I'm overwriting a differeing instance, rather than updating it?

Comment: Maybe. At any rate, it's a infamous pitfall in integration tests to use one context instance for the Arrange, Act and Assert phases. That doesn't reflect the real-life scenario. Whichever use case you want to test (Act), make sure that case has a new context instance.